# Google app engine: Separating test and production version of cloud endpoints

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, testing, google-cloud-endpoints

I made a project on the google app engine, following the multi-class API endpoints tutorial in the official documentation.

I need multiple projects (frontends, mobile, server,..) to be able to make API calls onto these java end points.

This works, but using versions has proven difficult.
I tried modifying the version in the appengine-web.xml.
Using mvn appengine:update and endpoint generation, I can deploy to the default version on the cloud, but this ignores the version I specified in the xml.

Using appcfg, I can deploy to other versions but then they do not include my endpoints.

Without versions, I would need to use a seperate project for the development/test environment and one for the production environment.

Additionally, I want to use different versions for the data store, but I can't find a lot of information on this. Having a seperate data store for testing and production seems to require making a seperate project.

So is this the normal way to work with test environments? Test and deploy to a seperate project with a test data store? Or is there a way to create a development version and a production version and have their endpoints be seperately callable and make seperate data store calls.

Thanks and good day.

Comment: I believe it's the recommend approach to provision a separate project for each environment dev, test & prod, see this section in the App Engine checklist https://cloud.google.com/appengine/checklist#provisioning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is recommended to Provision GCP Projects for each of your development environments (e.g. Dev, Test, Prod.), this approach may be a bit overkill for a one man team working on a relatively simple app.

I believe you should take a look at [Namespace API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy#Java_Other_uses_for_the_Namespaces_API). It is being used to reliably serve different applications/customers from the same GAE instances. Currently supports only:

- Datastore
- Memcache
- Task queue
- Search

but I hope it will suit your needs.

Comment: I will go with the multiple project solution, as the team I am working with needs a solid test setup.

Thanks and good day

Comment: Another option to have different endpoints URLs for the same project aside from only versions is to use modules https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/ I'd also recommend having a separate project to avoid confusion and mistakes